# Sonar project TimeoutException when looking for duplications  

Tags: timeout, sonarqube

We have a large project that is timing out in Sonar.  Any ideas?

```
[sonar:sonar] [WARN]  Timeout during detection of duplications for /apps/crtabm/Jenkins/home/jobs/sonar-java-batch-trunk/workspace/java/com/cis/MonteCarloLookup/MCCDSTableMid.java
[sonar:sonar] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
[sonar:sonar]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:228) [na:1.6.0_12]
[sonar:sonar]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91) [na:1.6.0_12]
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.plugins.cpd.SonarEngine.analyse(SonarEngine.java:153) [sonar-cpd-plugin-2.11.jar:na]
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.plugins.cpd.CpdSensor.analyse(CpdSensor.java:82) [sonar-cpd-plugin-2.11.jar:na]
[sonar:sonar]   at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64) [sonar-batch-2.11.jar:na]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

This same question appears on the Sonar Bug Tracker here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3050

Looking at the comments you can see that the problem should be addressed in the Sonar 2.13 release which is due out in January 2012. I'm having the same problem with my Gradle build, but trust that 2.13 will fix it.

[Update] I've upgraded to Sonar 2.13 and no longer see a memory problem with Duplications.